# How was the filter done to photographs

Tags: filter

I was asked to mimic the following using RMagick (which uses ImagMagick within the Ruby programming languages) applied to photos.

[image]

Anyone know
a) were these likely originally photos, or were they hand drawn?
b) if they were photos, how are these effects created?  I'm thinking it's something like posterize and some sketch filter, along with a texture that gets overlayed on a white background, and then finally the coffee stains are applied.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Those look hand drawn. You could try using Photoshop's brush stroke filters (accented edges might the closest), and then mount it on a brown paper background, but it will still be some way off in terms of similarity. Hand drawn images will still be as close as you can get.

Answer (score 1):

Not only is this art hand-drawn, but including it here without attribution is not really a nice thing to do. I wouldn't mind knowing who the artist is.

Comment: Client sent it to me, and it was done for them and they own rights, so I can't disclose.

Comment: Is your client sending you art works and asking you to magically make image filters to turn photos into art of this caliber? If so, I'd suggest finding saner clients. ;)

Comment: Your client owns the rights but they don't mind you posting the image to the web?

But, back to the original question, your client should commission more art from the same artist. That way they will all match.